# Find the general term formula for the sequence $(u_n)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Find the general term formula for the sequence $(u_n)$ defined by
\begin{cases}
u_{3n} &=u_n+u_{n-1}\\ 
 u_{3n+1} &=u_n+u_{n-1} \\ 
 u_{3n+2} &=u_n+u_{n-1} \\
u_0=1&,u_1=u_2=1
\end{cases}
I found $u_3,u_4,\cdots u_{27}$ but I couldn't find the general term formula. I think the linear differential equation is also not applicable.

Comment: Let $x_n=u_{3n}=u_{3n+1}=u_{3n+2}$, or equivalently $u_n=x_{\lfloor n/3\rfloor}$, to accelerate the sequence. $$x_0=1,\quad x_n=x_{\lfloor n/3\rfloor}+x_{\lfloor(n-1)/3\rfloor}$$ It appears to me (after plotting $100$ terms) that this sequence hits all positive integers (never decreasing), and the number of times a term is repeated only depends on its $2$-adic valuation. Specifically, if $x_n=2^e\cdot m$ where $m$ is odd, then the number of different $n'$ such that $x_{n'}=x_n$ seems to be $(3^e+1)/2$.

Comment: Writing $n$ in ternary should help.

Comment: It is clear by induction, looking at the trits, that $x_n=2^e$ for $n$ in the interval $[(3^e-1)/2,(3^e-1)]$, that is, $[11\ldots11_{\text{ter}},22\ldots22_{\text{ter}}]$. In particular, this contains the interval $[20\ldots00_{\text{ter}},22\ldots22_{\text{ter}}]$, so if the leftmost trit of $n$ is $2$ then $x_n$ is a power of $2$. If instead the leftmost trit is $1$, so $n=3^e+m$ for some $m<3^e$, then $x_n=2^e+x_m$.

Comment: Thus, if we write $n$ in ternary as a sequence of $1$'s and $0$'s on the left, and a $2$ in the middle, and anything on the right, then we can break off those left trits, converting the powers of $3$ to powers of $2$, and then add a final power of $2$ for the remaining sequence of trits that starts with $2$.

Comment: For example: $$n=11012210_{\text{ter}}$$ $$n=1\cdot3^7+1\cdot3^6+0\cdot3^5+1\cdot3^4+2\cdot3^3+2\cdot3^2+1\cdot3^1+0\cdot3^0$$ $$x_n=1\cdot2^7+1\cdot2^6+0\cdot2^5+1\cdot2^4+2^4\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$$

Comment: @mr_e_man  It's not correct. Can you please try it with $u_{3277}=127$? With your calculation, it results in $128$.

Comment: Well, if there are no $2$ trits at all, then the final term to add is $2^0=1$. This follows from the recursive equation I've provided: if $n=3^e+0$ then $x_n=2^e+x_0$, and we know $x_0=1$. So: $$n=3277=11111101_{\text{ter}}$$ $$\lfloor n/3\rfloor=1111110_{\text{ter}}$$ $$\qquad\qquad=3^6+3^5+3^4+3^3+3^2+3^1+0$$ $$u_n=x_{\lfloor n/3\rfloor}=2^6+2^5+2^4+2^3+2^2+2^1+1$$ $$=127$$

Answer (score 3):

We consider a generating function
\begin{align*}
U(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}u_nx^n\tag{1}
\end{align*}
of OPs recurrence relation
\begin{align*}
u_{3n} &=u_n+u_{n-1}\qquad\qquad n\geq 1\\ 
 u_{3n+1} &=u_n+u_{n-1} \tag{2}\\ 
 u_{3n+2} &=u_n+u_{n-1} \\
u_0&=u_1=u_2=1
\end{align*}
and derive a functional relation for $U$. We also show that $U$ is related with the generating function $V$
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{V(x)}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}v_nx^n
&\color{blue}{=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}3^{n+1}\frac{x^{2^n}}{1+x^{2^n}}}\tag{3}\\
&\color{blue}{=\frac{3}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(3^n+1\right)\frac{x^{2^n}}{1-x^{2^{n+1}}}}\tag{4}
\end{align*}

**A Functional relation of $U$:**

We obtain from (2)
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{U(x)}&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}u_nx^n\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}u_{3n}x^{3n}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}u_{3n}x^{3n+1}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}u_{3n}x^{3n+2}\\
&=\left(1+x+x^2\right)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}u_{3n}x^{3n}\\
&=1+x+x^2+\left(1+x+x^2\right)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}u_{3n}x^{3n}\\
&=1+x+x^2+\left(1+x+x^2\right)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(u_n+u_{n-1}\right)x^{3n}\\
&=1+x+x^2+\left(1+x+x^2\right)\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}u_nx^{3n}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}u_nx^{3n+3}\right)\\
&=\frac{1-x^3}{1-x}+\frac{1-x^3}{1-x}\left(U(x^3)-u_0+x^3U(x^3)\right)\\
&=\frac{1-x^3}{1-x}+\frac{1-x^3}{1-x}\left(\left(1+x^3\right)U(x^3)-1\right)\\
&\color{blue}{=\frac{1-x^6}{1-x}U(x^3)}\tag{5}
\end{align*}

> According to (5) we are looking for a function $U$ which fulfills
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{U(x)=\frac{1-x^6}{1-x}U(x^3)}
> \end{align*}

**Table values of $U$:** We list the number of occurrences of values $u_n$ for small $n$. We denote this number $v_n$ and look for  regularities. We obtain
\begin{align*}
\begin{array}{lrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr}
u_n&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16\\
v_n&\color{blue}{3}&\color{blue}{6}&3&\color{blue}{15}&3&6&3&\color{blue}{42}&3&6&3&15&3&6&3&\color{blue}{123}\\
\\
u_n&17&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25&26&27&28&29&30&31&32\\
v_n&3&6&3&15&3&6&3&42&3&6&3&15&3&6&3&\color{blue}{366}\\
\\
u_n&33&34&35&36&37&38&39&40&41&42&43&44&45&46&47&48\\
v_n&3&6&3&15&3&6&3&42&3&6&3&15&3&6&3&123\\
\\
u_n&49&50&51&52&53&54&55&56&57&58&59&60&61&62&63&64\\
v_n&3&6&3&15&3&6&3&42&3&6&3&15&3&6&3&\color{blue}{1\,095}\\
\end{array}
\end{align*}
We observe the natural numbers $u_n$ are exhausted by $v_n$ by some kind of **sieve** which *partitions* the natural numbers. A starting value for each partition is marked blue. We list the partitions indicated by the table values more compactly as
\begin{align*}
v_{2n+1}&=\frac{3}{2}\left(3^0+1\right)=3\qquad\qquad\ \  n\geq 0\\
v_{2(2n+1)}&=\frac{3}{2}\left(3^1+1\right)=6\qquad\qquad\ \  n\geq 0\\
v_{2^2(2n+1)}&=\frac{3}{2}\left(3^2+1\right)=15\qquad\qquad\  n\geq 0\\
v_{2^3(2n+1)}&=\frac{3}{2}\left(3^3+1\right)=42\qquad\qquad\  n\geq 0\\
v_{2^4(2n+1)}&=\frac{3}{2}\left(3^4+1\right)=123\qquad\qquad n\geq 0\\
v_{2^5(2n+1)}&=\frac{3}{2}\left(3^5+1\right)=366\qquad\qquad n\geq 0\\
&\vdots\\
\color{blue}{v_{2^k(2n+1)}}&\color{blue}{=\frac{3}{2}\left(3^k+1\right)}\qquad\qquad\qquad n,k\geq 0\tag{6}
\end{align*}

**Generating function $V$:**

> We derive from (6) a generating function $V$ as
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{V(x)}&=3\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x^{2k+1}+6\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x^{2(2k+1)}\\
> &\qquad+15\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x^{2^{2}(2k+1)}+\cdots\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{3}{2}\left(3^n+1\right)\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x^{2^{n}(2k+1)}\\
> &=\frac{3}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(3^n+1\right)x^{2^{n}}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(x^{2^{n+1}}\right)^{k}\\
> &\color{blue}{=\frac{3}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(3^n+1\right)\frac{x^{2^{n}}}{1-x^{2^{n+1}}}}
> \end{align*}
> in accordance with (4).

**Generating function $U$:**

We derive  a representation of the generating function $U$ with the help of $V$. We need additionally the sum of the coefficients of $V$ and recall we can get these values by multiplication of $V$ with $\frac{1}{1-x}$. We consider
\begin{align*}
V(x)&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}v_nx^n=\frac{3}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(3^n+1\right)\frac{x^{2^{n}}}{1-x^{2^{n+1}}}\\
&=3x+6x^2+3x^3+15x^4+3x^5+6x^6+3x^7+42x^8\\
&\qquad+3x^9+6x^{10}+\cdots\\
W(x)&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}w_nx^n=\frac{1}{1-x}V(x)\\
&=3x+9x^2+12x^3+27x^4+30x^5+36x^6+39x^7+81x^8\\
&\qquad+84x^9+90x^{10}+\cdots\\
\end{align*}

> We obtain using coefficients of $V(x)$ and $W(x)$
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{U(x)}&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}u_nx^n\\
> &=\left(1+x+x^2\right)+2\left(x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6+x^7+x^8\right)\\
> &\qquad+3\left(x^9+x^{10}+x^{11}\right)+4\left(x^{12}+x^{13}+\cdots+x^{26}\right)\\
> &\qquad+5\left(x^{27}+x^{28}+x^{29}\right)+\cdots\\
> &=\frac{1-x^3}{1-x}+2x^3\frac{1-x^6}{1-x}+3x^9\frac{1-x^3}{1-x}+4x^{12}\frac{1-x^15}{1-x}\\
> &\qquad+5x^{27}\frac{1-x^3}{1-x}+\cdots\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nx^{w_{n-1}}\frac{1-x^{v_n}}{1-x}}
> \end{align*}

**Note:** The coefficients $3,9,12,27,30,36,39,81,84,90,\ldots$ of $W(x)$ are stored in OEIS as *[A081601](https://oeis.org/A081601)*. A generating function which is nearly $W(x)$ is given as
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\frac{x}{1-x}\sum_{k\geq 0} 3^{k+1}\frac{x^{2^k}}{1 + x^{2^{k}}}}
\end{align*}
from which the representation (3) for $V(x)$ follows.

Comment: You're welcome! The sequence problem you provided is one I encountered while working with the generating function. The coefficient you've given for $x^n$ in the generating function is what I need to find. Do you have any method for finding the coefficient of $x^n$ for the given generating function?

Comment: Another similar issue is presented here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4807980/finding-the-coefficient-of-a-generating-function-f

Comment: @Math_fun2006: I've added some info.