# Finding the coefficient of a generating function $f$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, generating-functions

Finding the coefficient of a generating function
$$f(x)=\dfrac{(1+x^4)(1+x^{4^2}) \cdots (1+x^{4^n})\cdots}{1-x}$$
I once searched for the problem when replacing the number $4$ with the number $2$. At that point, it is possible to simplify $f$. The above issue is not straightforward for me.

Answer (score 1):

If we expand $\prod\limits_{k=1}^\infty (1+x^{4^k})$, we get the sum of $x^n$ over all $n$ that only have even positive powers of $2$ in binary.

Dividing this by $1-x$ is equivalent to multiplying it by $1+x+x^2+\dots$, thus $[x^n] f(x)$ is the number of integers from $0$ to $n$ that only have even powers of $2$ in their binary representation.

While exact number can also be derived from the binary representation of $n$, it isn't very pretty.

Comment: Can you calculate the coefficient for $x^{2023}$?

Comment: I think so. Before that, could you please share the source of the problem?

Comment: The problem above is part of a larger task I am working on involving generating function. It arose unexpectedly. Initially, I thought it was straightforward, but upon closer examination, it turned out to be different from what I initially thought.

Comment: $2023 = 2^{10}+2^9+2^8+\dots+2^5+2^2+2^1+2^0$. There are three groups to consider.

1. Numbers below $2^{10}$. They can only use $2^2, 2^4, 2^6, 2^8$ in their binary, so there are $2^4$ such numbers.
2. Numbers at least $2^{10}$, but below $2^{10}+2^9$. They must have $2^{10}$ in their binary, and besides that they can use $2^2, 2^4, 2^6, 2^8$, so it's extra $2^4$ options for us.
3. Numbers at least $2^{10}+2^9$, but at most $2023$. They all have $2^9$, an odd power of $2$, in their binary, which disqualifies them from consideration.

Thus, the answer for $n=2023$ should be $2^4+2^4=32$.

Comment: In this case, it will be challenging to derive a general formula for the coefficient of $x^n$

Comment: Yes, that's what I said in the last paragraph of the answer. To get a general formula, you can say that if $n = 2^{k_1}+\dots+2^{k_t}$, where $k_1 > \dots > k_t$, and first $m$ out of $t$ powers are positive and even, then the coefficient near $n$ seems to be
$$
\sum\limits_{i=1}^{m} 2^{k_i/2-1} + \begin{cases}
2^{\lfloor k_{m+1}/2\rfloor},& m < t, \\
1, & m=t.
\end{cases}
$$